# Why can I instantiate a class derived from an abstract class without overriding all abstract methods?

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class, python-2.x

Following a number of tutorials on the internet, I've created this example:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def Foo(self): 
        print('Foo base')

    @abstractmethod
    def Bar(self):
        print('Bar base')

class Sub(Base):

    def Foo(self):
        print('Foo sub')

    # no sub implementation of Bar

s = Sub() # why does this work?
s.Foo() # prints "Foo sub"
s.Bar() # prints "Bar base" (which makes sense if it's
        # **not** inheriting from an abstract class)
```

It's my understanding that you need to override all abstract methods when you inherit from a class that contains abstract methods. Why does this work?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: The problem is that you're using Python 2 syntax for abstract classes but executing in a Python 3 environment. Change your Base class declaration to `class Base(metaclass=ABCMeta):` (the Python 3 way of declaring an abstract class). You will now get a Type Error both on instantiating the Base class and instantiating the Sub class without overriding all abstract methods.

---

Slightly longer explanation - apparently this changed between Python 2 and 3, **however** the Python 2 version is *still valid code in Python 3*. It is not a *breaking* change in the sense that the code still executes (it just runs a little.... differenty). You are merely inheriting from the base object class. You will receive no warnings or errors and apparently the Python interpreter will just discard the `@abstractmethod` annotations.

Also, this change is not noted in any of the "Python 2 vs Python 3"/"Differences between Python 2 and 3" lists/articles that I have been able to find.